# How do I do navigation in django?

Tags: django, navigation

I have a website that has tree structure. One "menu" contains 1st level items, another "sidemenu" contains 2nd + 3rd menu items.

Could anyone recommend *Django* application that integrates with `urlpatterns` for doing this or similar structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/navigation/